# Remove attribute ID from site-logo (Panels Page Elements)

Tags: panels

I use a module [panels everywhere](https://www.drupal.org/project/panels_everywhere) with *Omega 4*. I try to put a site-logo in header and footer but *Logo Page Element from Panels* takes site-logo and render it with ID. So I have same ID twice in my page.

***Header***

[image]

***Footer***

[image]

- How I can remove ID or render element with my markup?
- How I can create own element for panels?

Thank you

Comment: Could you please make title more unique? Each and every question about panels page elements here was asked because someone had problems, right? Ideally, title should be a question in it's own right, and body used only to provide details, context etc. Now I don't ask you to be ideal ;) but maybe few steps in that direction? :)

Comment: Ok, i think now is better :)

Comment: it attracted someone who could answer. Definite proof it's better :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This logo is created in [ctools_page_logo_content_type_render](http://api.drupalcommerce.org/api/Drupal%20Commerce/sites!all!modules!ctools!plugins!content_types!page!page_logo.inc/function/ctools_page_logo_content_type_render/DC) function. Unfortunately we can't alter code of this function.
As a solution you may create your custom Ctools content type plugin, that will return logo without 'id' attribute. You can find more information about Ctools plugins [here](http://morpht.com/posts/how-create-ctools-content-types-drupal-7).